# Qpid Proton Python Reconnect Attempt Every Minute

Tags: python, qpid, qpid-proton

I'm new to Qpid Proton Python and AMQP. There is one thing that I'm a bit stuck on which I hope I can get some support from the community.

One of my application requirements is to **re-attempt connection every minute** if the connection from my application to the message broker (ActiveMQ) has been lost.

From the source code and this: [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq/7.5/pdf/using_the_amq_python_client/Red_Hat_AMQ-7.5-Using_the_AMQ_Python_Client-en-US.pdf) (Section 5.2.4, page 14), it seems like I can create a custom Backoff instance to the "reconnect" parameter when calling the "container.connect()" method during on_start event.

So I did something like this for my custom Backoff instance:

```
class Backoff:
    """
    A modified reconnect strategy that retries, every 60s. 
    Repeated calls to :meth:`next` returns a value for the next delay
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.delay = 60

    def reset(self):
        """
        Reset the backoff delay to 60 seconds.
        (This method is required for Qpid Proton Library)
        """
        self.delay = 60

    def next(self):
        """
        Modified the backoff mechanism to attempt reconnect every 60s

        :return: The next delay in seconds.
        :rtype: ``float``
        """
        return self.delay
```

During on_start:

```
def on_start(self, event):
    self.container = event.container
    self.conn = self.container.connect(
        url=self.url, user=self.user, password=self.password, reconnect=Backoff())
```

Questions:

1. May I know how can I test if this is actually working fine? I placed print statements in the "next()" method of my custom Backoff instance and disconnected my Wifi to simulate a disconnect, however, the reconnection attempt doesn't seem to work.
2. As the container runs, how can I capture disconnection events and attempt reconnection?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated, thank you!